# How to serve dynamically updated videos?

Tags: javascript, meteor, video-streaming

I crated a Meteor app that somehow enable user to upload video and play it in a playlist. Initially I serve the videos by using Meteor as well (create another empty app, put in public folder and run on different port).

However I notice that it takes huge amount of memory, as if it loads the whole video into memory and serve it instead of by chunks/blocks. Since this app will take videos from user, there is a chance that eventually the server will crash due to storing every videos inside memory.

I tried looking at the ffserver, but somehow it depends on the configuration of the file, instead of serving the whole folder. That means I have to specifically setup a file as a feed then configure it as a stream. I can't see how that will work with my app.

Is there any add-on for this type of file-serving in Meteor? How should I tackle this problem? What is the suitable server-framework for this job?

Answer (score 1):

I have used collectionFS (https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) for such tasks. They offer 3 different types of storage for uploaded media. It is very easy to use. Excerpt from README:

```
There are currently three available storage adapters, which are in separate packages. 
Refer to the package documentation for usage instructions:

cfs:gridfs: Allows you to save data to mongodb GridFS.
cfs:filesystem: Allows you to save to the server filesystem.
cfs:s3: Allows you to save to an Amazon S3 bucket.
```

Comment: I use the same thing @Nate. But the thing is, if u are to use Meteor serving these video, it would likely to consume way too many resources (its like its taking the total video bit by bit, for example 800mb video would use 800mb RAM). So I ended up using NGINX for serving the video. much better.